# Working Directory on Remote Git Repo Using Egit

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, egit, rcs

I need to set up a Git repo that my team can use, not only to track changes but also to have access to a working directory. I'm using egit on Eclipse.

I have successfully set up a bare git repo, but I cannot get a full remote repo to work. Can a remote repo even be a full repo instead of bare? How would I set up a full repo with working directory as a remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

Did you understand that git is a distributed system? Since you taged your question with rcs, you have to learn that this is fundamental difference.

Typically you work with a central repo. And every developer first clones this one and then pushed and pulls changes to and from this repo from his local one.

To get started have look at [github](https://github.com/). It provied all you need to host a central repo (and much more). If you need other options checkout [8 ways to share your git repository](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/) as a starting point for other repo hosting options.